# Oracle to SQL Server Migration : Equivalent of Oracle GROUP_ID() function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, migration

im looking for an equivalent way to do :

**`HAVING (GROUP_ID()=0) -- ORACLE`**

in SQL Server 2008.

Thanks :)

Comment: For the SQL Server people here, it would be helpful to explain what `GROUP_ID()` actually does, and/or link to the documentation.

Comment: I am not that familiar with `GROUP_ID()` but I might look at `DENSE_RANK()`

Comment: You are probably looking to do a SELECT DISTINCT [column names] @Pondlife http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions061.htm